# Chrome: how to open a local pdf on a specific page

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, network-protocols

For an online pdf I can simply add `#page=10` after the url to open the pdf on the page 10.

But this doesn't work for local pdf. [*2020 edit: this is now working for local pdf also cf. the selected answer*]

Let's say I open this url `file:///C:/Users/Me/Desktop/My%20Documents/textbook.pdf` in chrome.
If I add `#page=10` at the end of the link (the pdf has more than 50 pages), then chrome returns this error:

```
Your file was not found It may have been moved or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUNDthis url
```

Also Chrome change the url (cf My%2520Documents): `file:///C:/Users/Me/Desktop/My%2520Documents/textbook.pdf%23page=10`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For my Chrome(Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit))
It works with #page=number, if I open a new tab and paste the link:
`file:///D:/test.pdf#page=5`
Chrome will open the pdf at page 5.

Comment: Currently using Firefox 88.0.1 and it works on my browser, with both local and online PDFs.